# Понятие «абстракция» и понятие «объявление»

Tags: c++, c

Диалог:
**[Преподаватель]**: Абстракцию данных изучали?
**[Я]**: А подробнее, что именно?
**[Преподаватель]**: Абстракция - это отделение кода от заголовков. С оставлением прототипов заголовков в файле .h и вынесением всей реализации в .cpp.
**[Я]**: Вряд ли можно назвать это абстракцией. Это мы проходили.
**[Одна из студенток]**: А как это назвать тогда?
**[Я]**: Отделение объявления от определения (реализации).
**[Преподаватель]**: Ну так это и есть абстракция.
**[Я]**: Абстракция применяется в ООП в другом ключе...
**[Преподаватель]**: И то, и другое - это абстракция, просто разной направленности.

У меня есть сомнения насчет применения этих двух понятий в одном ключе.
Что вы думаете?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115343/discussion-between-gbg-and-eanmos).

Comment: Вы правы. ......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если зайти на Википедию, то можно обнаружить статью [Абстракция данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), где оно определяется как

> Абстра́кция в объектно-ориентированном программировании — это использование только тех характеристик объекта, которые с достаточной точностью представляют его в данной системе. Основная идея состоит в том, чтобы представить объект минимальным набором полей и методов и при этом с достаточной точностью для решаемой задачи.

В разделе ссылок в статье приводится статья [Бьерн Страуструп — Абстракция данных в языке С++](http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/cpp/cpp-data-abstraction.html?showall=&start=0), где понятие более детально рассматривается в контексте C++ и определяется как

> Фундаментальная идея состоит в разделении несущественных деталей реализации подпрограммы и характеристик существенных для для корректного ее использования.

Хотя разделение кода между заголовочными файлами и файлами реализации может быть необходимо при создании абстракций данных, само по себе такое разделение не является средством создания абстракций. Такое разделение существует так как по историческим причинам в С/С++ используется раздельная компиляция с текстовым препроцессором, который на первом этапе собирает из множества текстовых файлов один длинный текст единицы трансляции.

Comment: Студень прав и неправ одновременно) Если заголовочный файл снабдить просто объявами - ИМХО, абстракцией, А ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ ДАННЫХ, тут и не пахнет. Чисто форматинг в угоду среде сборки.

А вот если снабдить грамотными комментами ... тогда ДА! Уходим от частностей, переходим к важностям - и вперед в космос.

Таково мое ИМХО!

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы сначала выразили несогласие, а потом буквально скопировали мою идею (мой ответ появился раньше вашего) о том, что разделение на h и cpp к абстракции отношения не имеет?

Comment: Разделение заголовков и кода к абстракции имеет отношение ... ПРИ УСЛОВИИ ... что происходит отделение реализации от назначения. А это (подчеркиваю ИМХО) возможно только при наличии комментов в заголовках.

Иначе это игра в "требования" системы сборки.

Comment: @gbg я только привел определения из статей по ссылкам, из которых следует, что  определение, данное преподом, некорректное

Comment: @Majestio А как же самодокументируемый код?

Comment: @user7860670 - так что, теперь у вас переменилось мнение и "абстрактный класс" все же стал средством реализации "абстракции" в ООП?

Comment: @gbg Оно не переменилось, абстрактный класс как был, так и остается средством создания абстракций в С++, одним из многих.

Comment: @user7860670 - тогда что делает под моим ответом ваш комментарий о том что "абстракция" != "абстрактный класс" ?

Comment: @gdb Так создание абстракций не ограничивается абстрактными классами. Вы же в курсе, что вышеупомянутые интерфейсы в С++ можно реализовывать и не прибегая к абстрактным классам?

Comment: @user7860670, самодокументируемый код - щетаю перпендикулярен! Покажи мне самодокументируемый код, который распишет назначение метода/функции по-человечьи? Наличие блоков комментирования "перед" - не является еще документированием. Фуфло. Шняга. Гон.

Comment: @user7860670 в пределах студенческого программирования инструмент ровно один - наследование и полиморфизм. Если начинать выходить за эти рамки, можно в очередной раз запутать студентов, не создав в их сознании хотя бы минимально систематизированной опоры, на основании которой они уже самостоятельно смогут изучить все остальное.

Comment: @gbg, ололо!!! А как же автоматное программирование, как же switch-технология? Ну с ООП ты конечно перегнул. ООП - одна из "шляп", на которую когда-то все рукоблудили. Когда она молодая была.

Comment: Почему «*само по себе такое разделение не является средством создания абстракций*»? Сокрытие детали реализации некоторого компонента системы в наборе единиц трансляции и предоставление интерфейса к этому компоненту через файл `.h` эквивалентно понятию абстрагирования (согласно [этому](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) определению). Следовательно, в частных случаях разделение кода на `.h` и `.c` файлы является средством создания абстракций.

Answer (score 2):

*Удаляторам и минусаторам настоятельно рекомендую отправиться в комментарии и изложить свои аргументы. А также вспомнить о пирамиде Грэма и ее отношению к дискуссии*

В контексте C++ "абстракция" (в рамках студенческого и школьного программирования) имеет вполне четкий смысл - это использование класса с чисто виртуальными методами. В нем интерфейс к объекту *действительно* отделен от реализации, так как реализацию предоставляет экземпляр-наследник.

Разделение на *.h и *.cpp - это следствие технологического процесса сборки программы на C++ (машины были слабенькие, памяти мало, поэтому появилось стремление сделать компилятор однопроходным. А для этого нужно иметь возможность объявить сущность до ее определения), и смешение его в кучу с *настоящей* абстракцией из ООП как раз и приводит к запутыванию студентов. В процессе преподавания такое нежелательно.

Почему вынос тел функций в *.cpp не является абстракцией? Да потому что нельзя в двух разных файлах держать функцию с одним и тем же именем - компоновщик будет ругаться, придется изобретать какой-то переключатель или тасовать файлы.

Comment: "абстракция" != "абстрактный класс"

Comment: @user7860670 аргументы какие-то будут? Если вы под "Абстракцией" изволите понимать широкое философское понятие абстракции, можно утонуть в рассуждениях.

Comment: "Удаляторам и минусаторам настоятельно рекомендую отправиться в комментарии" - поддерживаю! Отдельное обращение к "закрываторам": если не понимаете сути вопроса - лучше пройдите мимо. Плюсую. Peace!!!

Comment: Поддержу предыдущего комментатора. Вы явно путаете абстракцию и абстрактные классы.

Comment: @gbg, и тебе плюсую ))) Преподу, прежде чем преподавать "абстракцию данных", следовало бы изучить чуть более, чем полностью термины "абстракция" и "абстрагирование".

Comment: @Majestio а также историю языка, который он преподает. Чтобы понимать, откуда что берется и быть последовательным в изложении материала

Comment: @gbg Вы точно мне это хотели адресовать?

Comment: @V-Mor, вангую - это была осечка)

Comment: @gbg, `V-Mor` практически встал грудью на защиту твоего мнения. А ты его гнобишь. Не так штоле он повернулся?)))

Comment: @gbg тогда у меня много вопросов. "ту же когнитивную ошибку" это какую? А причём здесь весь остальной Ваш комментарий, вообще не понятно. Да, понятие широкое. Да, его можно применить неправильно. А можно и правильно. Вы его зачем-то сузили до одного из значений, о чём я и написал. Почему преподаватель не прав, если он имел в виду общее понятие, тоже не понятно.

Comment: @V-Mor Сначала. Кто у вас "предыдущий комметатор" и кто у вас "вы"? Если бы вы пользовались @-тегами, было бы гораздо понятнее, к кому вы обращаетесь и на кого ссылаетесь

Comment: Почему у меня навязчивое ощущение, что участники данной дискуссии видят в моём комментарии раз в 10 больше смысла, чем я в него вложил? я всего лишь согласился, что `"абстракция" != "абстрактный класс" `

Comment: @gbg так я ведь уточнил, какое именно мнение я поддерживаю. Его выразил только один из комментаторов.

Comment: так я и говорю, тегами надо пользоваться, тогда вас и поймут. Если открыть ленту, видно, что "предыдущий комментатор" у вас - это  @Majestio, который меня поддерживает.

Ну и напоминаю, что вам стоит для повышения качества дискуссии ознакомиться с пирамидой Грэма.

Answer (score 2):

Погуглил толкования на английском, одно из лучших описаний:

> Abstraction is one of the key concepts of object-oriented programming (OOP) languages. Its main goal is to handle complexity by hiding unnecessary details from the user.

Вольный перевод:

> Абстракция это одно из ключевых понятий в объектно-ориентированном программировании (ООП), чьё основное назначение – помогать справляться со сложностью скрывая ненужные детали от пользователя.

То есть, абстракция прямо вытекает в принципы ООП: наследование, инкапсуляция, полиморфизм. Инкапсуляция зачастую выглядит как классы и объекты, которые могут производить сложную логику предоставляя при этом простой интерфейс. В Си++ этот интерфейс выглядит в виде заголовочных файлов, но это лишь одно из технических воплощений как инкапсуляции, так и абстракции в целом. Инкапсуляция реализована и в виде модификаторов доступа полей в C++, `private`, `protected`, которые очень чётко говорят, что является деталями реализации и не должно заботить разработчика-пользователя класса. Но инкапсуляция существует и вне ООП, те же заголовочные файлы были и есть в языке Си, и используются там для тех же целей.

Абстракция также проявляется и в наследовании с полиморфизмом, когда мы можем использовать родительские/абстрактные классы или интерфейсы, и успешно производить какую-то логику с объектами даже не зная их точного типа.

Comment: Я могу СИДЕТЬ. Из этого вытекает, что я могу сидеть на ДИВАНЕ и пить вискарь, могу сидеть в КРЫТКЕ и есть баланду, а могу сидеть на КОРТАХ и лузгать семечки. Мое умение СИДЕТЬ - первично.

Это я к тому, что сидеть в сетях "техногогии ООП" можно тоже, но понятие СИДЕТЬ всеж первично. А где - это вторично. Поэтому давайте не будем натягивать сову на глобус, ей еще совиные яйца нести.